# <unknown>:0: error: IR generation failure: program too clever: variable collides with existing symbol OBJC_CLASS_$_UIDevice

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

**unknown:0: error: IR generation failure: program too clever: variable collides with existing symbol OBJC_CLASS_$_UIDevice**

This is the error message thrown by Xcode 7.0.1. I have no idea, what I did wrong to make Xcode throw this error. This error occurs when I try to build my project in swift.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a variable called UIDevice? Don't.

Comment: Nope. I'm just using this code to get the system version. 'UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion'. But I don't think it would be creating any problem as the program was getting built few hours earlier.

Comment: If you delete that line, does it solve the problem?

Comment: yes..it solved the problem. But then how do I detect the system version? Also I want to write it a single place and use it throughout the classes.

Comment: I can't see your code so I don't know what you're doing. But whatever it is, don't do it.

Comment: I was trying something like this:                                                                   'let iOSVersion          =   UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion' and then use it anywhere in my class.

Comment: But I can't reproduce the problem based on that. Try it yourself in an otherwise vanilla project. Only you can see what you're doing, and you're not being informative about what makes what you're doing special. But the problem is solved: Don't Do That.

Comment: I have added a screenshot in my original question. When I comment out the buggy line or delete it from the file, it build properly.

Comment: So you're trying to do this at top level of some class file. That's the problem. It's too soon. Do it as, say, an instance property of the AppDelegate property, or a static property of a struct.

Answer (score 6):

As used in a constant file. You may use something like this also

```
let IS_IPAD = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad)
let IS_IPHONE = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone)
```

In the Apple document, we may find this

> The UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() function is provided for use when
>   deploying to a version of the iOS less than 3.2. If the earliest
>   version of iPhone/iOS that you will be deploying for is 3.2 or
>   greater, you may use -[UIDevice userInterfaceIdiom] directly.

This is why we get error below

> IR generation failure: program too clever: variable collides with
>   existing symbol OBJC_CLASS_$_UIDevice

To solve this, just replace with this code

```
let IS_IPAD = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad
let IS_IPHONE = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a static property of a struct, like this:

```
struct Constants {
    static let iOSVersion = UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion
}
```

Now you can say `Constants.iOSVersion` anywhere in your program.